# How can I use laravel dusk with docker-compose?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-dusk

I'm sorry my English is not fluent...
I have a some problems.

I am using docker-compose to create development environment for Laravel application.
When I did build tests, I couldn't use Laravel Dusk...

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2' 

services:
  web: 
    build: ./docker-config/php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  nginx: 
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker-config/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - web

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: development
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testdb 
      MYSQL_USER: test 
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testdb
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=testdb
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /sessions

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

---

`DuskTestCase.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function baseUrl()
    {
        return 'http://nginx';
    }

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
       //static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless'
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)>setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

---

`ExampleTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }
}
```

I can acess to "http://localhost" and see text "Laravel".

`docker-compose exec web php artisan dusk`
after I goy an error messages.
I try `docker-compose run web composer update facebook/webdriver`. but I see some error...

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Error: Call to undefined method 
Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::getCapabilities()

/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:257
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:152
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:153
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:77
/var/www/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:21

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this actual reason of error (mine seems a bit different with code similar to yours) but for sure in line:

```
ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)>setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
```

you miss z`-` before `>setCapability`

It should be:

```
ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
```